# ssh and nodejs application

Tags: node.js, ssh

I have a nodejs application which run some shell commands. I want to execute these commands in another machine by using ssh.

I have this:

```
snapInfo(snapName: string) {
    return `snap info ${snapName}`;
}
```

I need something like this:

```
snapInfo(snapName: string) {
    return `ssh user@host snap info ${snapName}`;
}
```

the file is a .ts file. How can I do it? Any suggestions? It's the first time I see a nodejs app.

Thanks in regard

Comment: Here is a quick tutorial on how to do it: https://grizzlybit.info/blog/how-to-ssh-using-nodejs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the excellent [ssh2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2) module for Node.js.

`npm install ssh2`

And then you can connect to your remote system like this by adding a new function `execSSHCommand` which can be used instead of `execCommand` in the file shell-commands.ts.

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { promisify } from 'util';
import { exec } from 'child_process';
import { Client } from 'ssh2'

const exec_promise = promisify(exec);

function execute_over_ssh(cmd: string): Promise<{ stdout: string; stderr: string; }> {
  return new Promise<{ stdout: string; stderr: string; }>((resolve, reject) => {
    let conn = new Client();
    conn.on('ready', function () {
      let stdout = "", stderr = "";
      conn.exec(cmd, function (err, stream) {
        if (err) reject(err);
        stream.on('close', function (code, signal) {
          resolve({ stdout, stderr });
          conn.end();
        }).on('data', function (data) {
          stdout += data.toString('utf8');
        }).stderr.on('data', function (data) {
          stderr += data.toString('utf8');
        });
      });

    }).connect({ host: '127.0.0.1', port: 22, username: 'user', password: 'pass' });
  });
}


@Injectable()
export class ShellService {

  async execCommand(cmd: string, password?: string): Promise<string> {
    if (password) {
      // TODO: Possibly remove
      const command = `echo ${password} | sudo -S ${cmd}`;
      const { stdout, stderr } = await exec_promise(command);
      return stdout;
    } else {
      const command = `${cmd}`;
      const { stdout, stderr } = await exec_promise(command);
      return stdout;
    }
  }

  async execSSHCommand(cmd: string): Promise<string> {
    const command = `${cmd}`;
    const { stdout, stderr } = await execute_over_ssh(command);
    return stdout;
  }

}
```

Comment: I will write all the above inside the snapinfo function?

Comment: Yeah, pretty much. I can't really say much without looking at some more code. You can add it in the function or build a Promise around it

Comment: https://github.com/stavrosdro/microk8s-addons that's the project. You can find the above functiont there: microk8s-addons/microk8s-webconsole/server/src/core/services/shell/

Comment: I've updated the code based on your git repo. Unfortunately I can't test the code and I am not that good at Typescript.

Comment: it's not running. my editors shows an error here
`const { stdout, stderr } = await exec_promise(command);`

Comment: So I updated the shell.service.ts with the above code.I don't see any errors now. I have to make further changes in shell-commands.ts?

Comment: No, so you'll have to update the other files with `execSSHCommand` instead of `execCommand`, wherever applicable. You might have to figure this part out as I am not sure about the rest of the code and unfortunately cannot run it.

Comment: I tried to replace execCommand's code with execSSHCommand. I have promising results (a lit bit of functionality).

Comment: That&#39;s great! I&#39;ve used the ssh2 module in production for a couple of use cases and it works very well.

Comment: Actually I have half-functionality. Some parts are not working properly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194801/discussion-between-stephen-s-and-stavros-droutsas).

Comment: @StephenS I'm not sure how it behaves for this command `cd /var/www && git pull && npm install` Will it awaits for this command?

Comment: @HenonoaH It will not await. A stream is returned on exec and the stream closes when the command finishes execution. You can await on the stream's close event. But it's better to open a new question for this...